# Cannot instantiate interface 'ElasticsearchClient'

Tags: gradle, elasticsearch-7

The [official Elasticsearch docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/7.17/connecting.html) tell to instantiate `ElasticsearchClient` like this:

```
ElasticsearchClient client = new ElasticsearchClient(transport);
```

Once I write this in my Grails 3 application with Gradle build management, I get the following compilation error: `Cannot instantiate interface 'ElasticsearchClient'`

The `import` statement is: `import org.elasticsearch.client.ElasticsearchClient`.
Indeed, `ElasticsearchClient` gets resolved to:

```
package org.elasticsearch.client;
// ...
public interface ElasticsearchClient {
```

The Gradle dependency is: `compile 'org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:7.17.2'`

1. Why do they propose to instantiate an interface in their docs?
2. What can I do to make it compile and use the Elasticsearch client?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this was: `ElasticsearchClient` was mis-resolved to an old elasticsearch JAR file that had still been in my local user's `.gradle` directory. Removing the old JAR from `.gradle` enabled me to do the correct import.

The correct import is
`import co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient`
instead of
`import org.elasticsearch.client.ElasticsearchClient`